# AppIntro Kotlin только при первом запуске

Tags: android, kotlin

Помогите разобраться и реализовать метод показ AppIntro только при первом запуске.
AppIntro создал по этому ресурсу
https://github.com/AppIntro/AppIntro
Имею  SplashActivity ,MyCustomAppIntro,  MainActivity.
Показ при первом запуске : сперва всегда со Splash затем MyCustomAppIntro и MainActivity.
Если запуск не первый : Splash и MainActivity

```
class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        //hiding title bar of this activity
        window.requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
        //making this activity full screen
        window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash)

        //4second splash time
        Handler().postDelayed({
            //start main activity
            startActivity(Intent(this@SplashActivity, MyCustomAppIntro::class.java))
            //finish this activity
            finish()
        },2000)
    }
}
```

Следующий класс

```
class MyCustomAppIntro : AppIntro() {




    companion object {
        fun startActivity(context: Context) {
            val intent = Intent(context, MyCustomAppIntro::class.java)
            context.startActivity(intent)

        }
    }
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setTransformer(AppIntroPageTransformerType.Depth)
        // You can customize your parallax parameters in the constructors.
        setTransformer(AppIntroPageTransformerType.Parallax(
                titleParallaxFactor = 1.0,
                imageParallaxFactor = -1.0,
                descriptionParallaxFactor = 2.0
        ))

             // Make sure you don't call setContentView!

        // Call addSlide passing your Fragments.
        // You can use AppIntroFragment to use a pre-built fragment
        addSlide(
            AppIntroFragment.newInstance(
            imageDrawable = R.drawable.ayana,
                backgroundDrawable = R.color.black,
                        description = "Привет мой друг"

        ))
        addSlide(
                AppIntroFragment.newInstance(
                        imageDrawable = R.drawable.ayana,
                        backgroundDrawable = R.color.black,
                        description = "Меня зовут AYANA"
        ))
        addSlide(
                AppIntroFragment.newInstance(
                        backgroundDrawable = R.drawable.screen_3

                ))
    }

    override fun onSkipPressed(currentFragment: Fragment?) {
        super.onSkipPressed(currentFragment)
        // Decide what to do when the user clicks on "Skip"
        val intent = Intent(this,MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent);


        finish()
    }

    override fun onDonePressed(currentFragment: Fragment?) {
        super.onDonePressed(currentFragment)
        val intent = Intent(this,MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent);
        finish()
    }
```

И  MainActivity

Answer (score 1):

Добавил в splash

```
Handler().postDelayed({
            //start main activity

            val sharedpref: SharedPreferences =
                getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(
                    "com.justai.aimybox.assistant",
                    MODE_PRIVATE
                )

            val token: String? = sharedpref.getString("token", null)
            if (token == "False" || token == null) {
                // rest of the FirstTime Logic here
                startActivity(Intent(this@SplashActivity, MyCustomAppIntro::class.java))

                sharedpref.edit().putString("token", "true").apply()
            } else {
                // rest of the Not-FirstTime Logic here
                startActivity(Intent(this@SplashActivity, MainActivity::class.java))
            }
            //startActivity(Intent(this@SplashActivity, MyCustomAppIntro::class.java))
            //finish this activity
            finish()
        },2000)
```